# Update table records with jquery and mysql using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need help with updating the selected item from a list populated via php and updated with jquery, here is what I have:

my update.php front-end

```
 <?php include_once('db.php'); ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Update Collected</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 </head>

  <body>
  <?php 
  $sql="SELECT * FROM qrnumber";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);


  ?>
 <div class="container-fluid main">

      <div class="row-fluid ">   
         <div class="span12">  
         <span class="success"></span>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>id</th><th>Name</th><th>Points</th><th>Collected</th><th>Action</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
  <tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['points']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['total']; ?></td>
<!-- and so on -->
<td>

   <input id="total" class="required" type="text" name="total">
  <button class="update_btn" rel="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">update</button>

</td>
 </tr>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php
  // close connection
  mysql_close();
   ?>
  </table>
  </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){      

  $(function() {        
    $("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter({sortList:[[0,0],[2,1]], widgets: ['zebra']});
    $("#options").tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0]], headers: { 
            3:{sorter: false}, 4:{sorter: false}}});
   );   
 $('.update_btn').click(function(){
    $('.success').text("loading...");
     var id = $(this).attr('rel');
     var total = $('#total').val();
    $.post('call.php', {Id:id, Total:total}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
 });

   });
 </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

This is my process.php file

```
 <?php 
 include_once('db.php');
 var_dump($_POST);
 if (isset($_POST['collected'])){
$collected =  mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['collected']));
 }
 $id = $_POST['id'][0];
  $total = $_POST['total'];
  echo $id. $total;
   mysql_query("UPDATE qrnumber SET total='$total'
   WHERE id='$id'");

   ?>
```

The issue is that when I post a number to the input field, it makes connection to my processing php file, but does not update the content, it connects to db and passes the values from update.php to process file(call.php). Then, it sets all of the records to '0', can someone help, please.

Thanks,

jv

Comment: where are you making use of $collected in the query in process.php ?

Answer (score 1):

Your $_POST is wrong in PHP. PHP only creates an array of values in $_POST/$_GET if the fieldname submitted by the client ends with `[]` characters. e.g.

will produce the following $_POST array:

```
$_POST = array(
    'not_an_array' => 'bar'
    'is_an_array' => array (
       0 => 'baz'
       1 => 'qux'
    )
);
```

Since the `Id and`Total`you're submitting in the ajax call don't have`[]` in the names, they'll just be plain single values in PHP, e.g.

```
$id = $_POST['Id'];
$total = $_POST['Total'];
```

And nod that you're STILL vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, since you're trying to use `$id` directly in your query without escaping that either. **ANY** external data going into a query string is an attack vector. You cannot escape only SOME of the values and assume you're safe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know it sends me back an array, which is ok with me, as long as I can get the results back from the array and make the query to update the db table.

Comment: I've created a js fiddle, what I have currently works great for the first entry, but when I try the second entry or the next ones, it does not work. Here is what I have: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javivilchis/SrUEe/1/)